# Mobile Site - Content Star Rating

Tags: user-behavior, mobile-web, ratings, mobile-first

Is there a best practice or good example showing how a 5-star rating interaction would display on a mobile website for rating content?

See example below:
[image: Example]

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what exactly you mean by rating interaction?

Comment: How would a user give a rating? Small stars aren't exactly "touch-friendly" and the amount of real-estate to make them touchable would be nuts. I can't find an example of a mobile site that allows you to rate content. Are there any out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the **[Mobiscroll - Rating & Grading Scroller](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/rating)**!

**Highlights**

- Easy Product Ratings
- Maintains Post Data
- Updates HTML on Rating

**What to do**

- Tap on your Favorite Chocolate
- Rate Items
- Try Bubble Display Mode
- Try it on your phone at [msc.li/2t8w](http://msc.li/2t8w)

[image: default image]

**View for setting the rating:**

[image: set rating image]

Comment: That might work, I'll give that one a shot.

Comment: @AaronBenjamin - Ok, let us know!

Comment: Your screenshots are informative but the text of this answer reads more like a product recommendation than an actual answer - why is this method of interaction better than the one in the OP?

Comment: The question reads: _Is there a best practice or good example showing how a 5-star rating interaction would display on a mobile website for rating content?_ I answered it by giving an example of a mobile rating scroller that does exactly that. The question you are asking in your comment was never asked.

Comment: Yes, but why is this a good example - and what do the "features" of this particular tech have to do with the UX (i.e., what does it matter that it "maintains POST data" - you've just copied and pasted the product highlights into an answer)?  I guess I should have been clearer in my comment.  I would think to be of value to this site some explanation would be needed, otherwise, this question just feels like a shopping cart question.

Comment: I didn't feel any need to explain past what the images clearly show, which is a mobile friendly UX for rating content. It was exactly what the OP asked for and they marked this post as the answer, so clearly it's a useful answer and your DV was unwarranted.

Comment: The clickable area in the question is way too small. Code Mavericks answer was a correct suggestion, even with the pitch.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways for user to give a rating on mobile devices.  Below I'll show you three different methods of some sites/apps accomplish this.

**Google Play Store**
You've expressed concern about the limited real-estate in mobile view and how it could be hard for user to rate content.  Google Play just made the rating UI larger.  Instead of the small rating at the corner like in your mock up, you could use larger stars on the content detail page.

[image]

**Amazon.com**
Another method is to list out all the rating possibilities so user can clearly all the available ratings and can simply tap on the rating they wish to give from a list.

[image]

**Zappos.com**
If you have UI contrains and can only small star rating on the UI, you could use a light-box to display a list of the ratings when user tap on the smaller rating icons.

[image]